# netlogo checking patch color

Tags: netlogo

in simple words what I am struggling to do is:

if (colour of any patch = red) then execute some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if any? patches with [pcolor = red] [
  print "yes, there is at least one red patch"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only a turtle can check the pcolor. So this works:

```
ask turtles [show pcolor]
```

But this does not work (typed in on the Observer> prompt):

```
show pcolor
```

Comment: but i need to use the pcolor condition with if statement, in the go procedure. for exaplme: if any patch has a red colour then execute some code. thanks